# I Am trying to configure Mongo readonly connections to the secondary using Spring Jdbc on a Java Enterprise Application

Tags: spring, mongodb, jdbc

I used the following setting and it is not working as expected. The connections are only going to Primary. I need it to start going to Secondaries. I have 2 secondary mongo instances.

```
<bean id="secondaryPreferred" class="com.mongodb.ReadPreference" factory-method="secondary"/>

<bean id="MenuMongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="MongoDbFactory"/>
    <property name="writeConcern" value="${mongo.writeConcern}"/>
    <property name="readPreference" ref="secondaryPreferred"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your secondary bean referring to an actual subclass of ReadPreference class:

```
<bean id="secondaryPreferred" class="com.mongodb.TaggableReadPreference.SecondaryReadPreference"/>
```

Comment: tried this @daniel it didn't work. I Am wondering if this is bug in spring jdbc for mongo.